# python: list generated from dataframe in pandas is much longer than the dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

this code should generate a list called 'cat_list' of values taken from df['a'] according to their position in the 'cat' list. If df['a'] contains values not present in 'cat' list, then 0 should be appended to 'cat_list'.
'cat_list' should have length 6, but I am not sure why its length is 18.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': [0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6], 'b': [0.6, 0.8,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1],
     'c': [0.7, 0.3,0.9,0.4,1.0,0.2],'d': [1,0,0,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

cat=[0.6,0.3,0.1]
cat_list=[]
for i in df.a:
    for j in cat:
        if i == j:
            cat_list.append(cat.index(j))
        else:
            cat_list.append(0)

print(cat_list) # should print [2,0,1,0,0,0]
print(len(cat_list)) # should print 6, not 18
```

Comment: Length wise you have a loop over 6 elements over a loop over 3 elements.
Each run of the inner loop you append to cat_list so that will always be 18 elements unless you change how you append

Comment: paper pen debugging should tell the truth

Comment: hint: you need one explicit for loop not two

Comment: Sorry for my question but does it make sense if your expected outcome is `[2,0,1,0,0,0]` and  `[2,-1,1,-1,-1,0]` or `[2,nan,1,nan,nan,0]`. How do you make the difference between 0 (for 0.1) and 0 (for nothing)?

Answer (score 2):

Length wise you have a loop over 3 elements inside a loop over 6 elements. Together that is going to result in 6*3=18 elements.

Each run of the inner loop you append to cat_list rather than just when the item is found or once when it isn't.
I believe this is what you are trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': [0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6], 'b': [0.6, 0.8,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1],
     'c': [0.7, 0.3,0.9,0.4,1.0,0.2],'d': [1,0,0,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

cat=[0.6,0.3,0.1]
cat_list=[]
for i in df.a:
    found_in_cat=False
    for j in cat:
        if i == j:
            cat_list.append(cat.index(j))
     if not found_in_cat:
        cat_list.append(0)

print(cat_list) # should print [2,0,1,0,0,0]
print(len(cat_list)) # should print 6, not 18
```

I would, however, write it like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': [0.1, 0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6], 'b': [0.6, 0.8,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.1],
     'c': [0.7, 0.3,0.9,0.4,1.0,0.2],'d': [1,0,0,1,0,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

cat=[0.6,0.3,0.1]
cat_list=[]
for i in df.a:
    if i in cat:
        cat_list.append(cat.index(i))
    else:
        cat_list.append(0)

print(cat_list) # should print [2,0,1,0,0,0]
print(len(cat_list)) # should print 6, not 18
```

Comment: answer without explianation is more often than not worth nothing

Comment: @athing so what "explianation " you think I need

Comment: @jhylands let me correct his vote for you ~

Comment: you didnt have explanation at all when i dovnwoted and debugging is a important skill for programmer thats what i was try saying to question asker. still you dont explain the code you wrote

Comment: @BENY not sure what you mean you had answer somewhere here but i dont see anymore not enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

It is usually inefficient to use loops with dataframes.

You could use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) on the column "a" with a crafted [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), this will ensure to map 0 when the value is not found:

```
from collections import defaultdict
val = defaultdict(lambda :0, zip(cat, range(len(cat))))
df['a'].map(val).tolist()
```

output: `[2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

Altenatively, you could use a list comprehension and a classical dictionary, the use of `get` enable to set a default value when the key is missing:

```
val = dict(zip(cat, range(len(cat))))
[val.get(e, 0) for e in df['a'].values]
```

format of the used dictionary/defaultdict:

```
>>> val
{0.6: 0, 0.3: 1, 0.1: 2}
```